# How to maintain class consistency?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, generator

I am trying to write a basic blackjack game in python . But when I create a class object
e.g Card.card_1 or Deck.deck_1 they are Class objects but when I try and transfer them to another classes e.g 52 Card Objects to a Deck Object they seem to revert to lists, thus negating my instance methods. Could somebody tell me what I am missing?

Card_Class.py

```
value = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
suit = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]

class Card():
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        self.score = 0
```

Deck_Class.py

```
import Card_Class
import random 

class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []

    def populate_deck(self):
        for s in Card_Class.suit :
            for v in Card_Class.value:
                self.deck.append([s, v])
        return self.deck


    def get_card(self):
        return self.deck[0]
```

The get_card method returns a list type , despite my self.deck = [] , so it has changed from a deck object to a list object?

Answer (score 1):

All I see in your `populate_deck` method is an append to the deck list that adds a list:

```
self.deck.append([s, v])
```

That line clearly appends a list containing the current suit and value. There is no changing of types going on, the only things ever added are some lists. So your `self.deck` would look like

```
[["Hearts", "A"], ["Hearts", "2"], ["Hearts", "3"]]
```

etc.

You probably meant to add a new Card object using its constructor.

```
self.deck.append(Card_Class.Card(s,v))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add Card to your Deck whereas you are storing suit and value in deck. So call Card constructor using Card() with the right s and v value as follows:

```
def populate_deck(self):
    for s in Card_Class.suit :
        for v in Card_Class.value:
            self.deck.append(Card_Class.Card(s, v))
    return self.deck
```